# Gstreamer, how to route output to a file instead of the framebuffer

Tags: linux, gstreamer, framebuffer

Good afternoon,

I need to know how to use Gstreamer to send frame data to a file instead of the framebuffer.

I want to be able to open the file with another program, edit some video data, then forward to the framebuffer.

is there a gstreamer command for doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need a [filesink](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-filesink.html).

You can simply add one at the end of your pipeline:

```
mypipeline ! filesink location=myfile
```

This will write the stream into a file named myfile.